# how to add account team related list to accounts

Tags: account

I have to add account team as a related list to account .
Page layout for account is not editable i suppose.
I have enabled account team but i am not able to see it on account page layout
How do I do that?
Please help

Answer (score 1):

1- Create a look up field on Account Team(in case of custom object) referencing to Account, if not done already. This will create a look up relationship between Account & Account Team.
2- Open any Account Record and click on edit layout. Here, at the top you will see a palette, click on related lists. Drag that related lists to the layout and hit Save.

Comment: how do i add a new button to the account team related list

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not possible

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I think what you're looking for is this:

1. From Setup menu, go to **Build** -> **Customize** -> **Accounts** -> **Account Teams**
2. On the 'Account Team Setup' page, click "**Enable Account Teams**"
3. Click the checkbox next to "**Account Teams Enabled**"
4. On the 'Page Layout Selection' page, **click the checkbox next to each existing page layout that you want Account Teams to display on**.
5. Click "**Save**".

(It sounds like what you are missing is Step 4)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using VF page then you can use the following tag:

If not , Then
Click Add in the Default Account Team related list. Select users to add as members of your default account team. Select the access levels that each member should have on the accounts you own and the contacts, opportunities, and cases related to those accounts.

Thanks,
Vipul

Comment: how do i add a new button to the account team related list

Comment: You need to click on add button in the related list for adding the Team members.

Comment: no i have to edit the page layout for account team by adding a new custom  button however the list is not customizable

Comment: There is no page layout for the Account Team . I don't think so you can modify the layout of Account Team and add any new Customized button.

Comment: It's impossible, Please post an Idea over IdeaExchange.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open the Account Record.
2. Edit Layout.
3. Choose Related List
4. Drag the Account Team to the Related List page Layout section.

Please mark this answer as best answer if you are able to do it.

Comment: how do i add a new button to the account team related list

Comment: You need to click on add button in the related list for adding the Team members.